# Issues with java.io.File class

Tags: java

i saw this code:

```
File[] tofile = new File[destinationFolder, "filename.ext"];
```

I wonder if this code will work, I have used in a code and didn't see any files copied?
if not, how to create a file and specify its destination directory or path along with its name?

Comment: This code doesn't compile. Please post real code. Don't you mean to use parentheses instead of brackets? As to your concrete problem of the files not being copied, please show an SSCCE for that. It can have countless possible causes which likely no one will point all out for you.

Comment: Have you tried to compile it? That line is not valid Java.

Answer (score 2):

That line of code is not valid Java. I guess you mean something like this:

```
File tofile = new File(destinationFolder, "filename.ext");
```

And you expect that to copy a file.

This will not copy a file on disk. A `java.io.File` object is just a representation of a file path - it does not directly represent a physical file on disk. Creating a new `File` object does not create, or copy, a file on disk.

[This example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html) from Oracle's Java Tutorials shows how to copy a file, but it uses an API that's new in Java 7. If you're using an older version than Java 7, see [this](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/CopyFile.html), for example.